# If $\left<3\right> \cong \mathbb Z_2$ and $\left<2\right> \cong \mathbb Z_3$, why isn't $\left<3\right>\left<2\right> \cong \mathbb Z_2\mathbb Z_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$\left|\mathbb Z_{6}\right|=6=2 \cdot 3$. Since $\mathbb Z_{6}$ is abelian, all subgroups are normal and thus its Sylow subgroups are unique. $\left<3\right>$ is the $2$-Sylow, and $\left<2\right>$ is the $3$-Sylow. Also, $\left<3\right> \cap \left<2\right> = \{0\}$.

Now, $\mathbb Z_6 = \left<3\right>\left<2\right> \cong \left<3\right> \times \left<2\right>$.

Also, $\left<3\right> \cong \mathbb Z_2$ and $\left<2\right> \cong \mathbb Z_3$.

So, $\mathbb Z_6 \cong \left<3\right> \times \left<2\right> \cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$. That is $\mathbb Z_6 \cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$

So, why doesn't it hold that $\mathbb Z_6 = \left<3\right>\left<2\right> \cong \mathbb Z_2\mathbb Z_3$?

I know $\mathbb Z_2\mathbb Z_3=\{0,1,2,3\}$, but if $\left<3\right> \cong \mathbb Z_2$ and $\left<2\right> \cong \mathbb Z_3$, why isn't $\left<3\right>\left<2\right> \cong \mathbb Z_2\mathbb Z_3$?

Why does it hold that $\left<3\right> \times \left<2\right> \cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$, but it doesn't hold that $\left<3\right>\left<2\right> \cong \mathbb Z_2\mathbb Z_3$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G$ is a group and $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ then $HK = \{hk\mid h\in H, k\in K\}$. Presumably you mean $\mathbb Z_2\mathbb Z_3$ to be the set $$\{0+0,0+1,0+2,1+0,1+1,1+2\} = \{0,1,2,3\},$$ but I don't think it makes sense to add an element of $\mathbb Z_2$ to an element of $\mathbb Z_3$ since there is no obvious way to treat them as subgroups of some group.

In any case, if $G_1$ has subgroups $H_1$ and $K_1$ and $G_2$ has subgroups $H_2$ and $K_2$ such that $H_1 \cong H_2$ and $K_1 \cong K_2$ then it does not follow that $H_1H_2 \cong K_1K_2$.

For example $G_1 = \mathbb Z_6$, $H_1 = \langle 3 \rangle$, $K_1 = \langle 2 \rangle$, $G_2 = S_3$, $H_2 = \langle (12) \rangle$, $K_2 = \langle (123) \rangle$.

Comment: Right. It wouldn't make sense to add an elt. of $\mathbb Z_2$ to $\mathbb Z_3$. I didn't notice that. Nice example.